# How can I pass HTML code stored in a string variable to a view in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an action which is defined like this one:

```
    public ActionResult TempOutput(string model)
    {
        return View((object)model);
    }
```

I also have its view, which is defined like this:

```
@model String

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TempOutput";
}

<h2>TempOutput</h2>

@Model
```

And, at one point in my code, I call the action method and the view with this line of code:

```
return RedirectToAction("TempOutput", "SEO", new { model = tmpOutput });
```

The point is that, it works all fine when I have a short string, but in my case tmpOutput is a string variable which holds a long HTML code. The thing is that I want to pass that HTML code inside my view, but I don't want it to be displayed as a normal text, but I want it to be parsed as a HTML code and change the view. Currently, when I run the code, I get an error message saying:

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the
>   query string is too long.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is that `redirecttoaction` makes a new (302) http request and your `'model'` which you are sending will be send with querystring and querystring has a limit then instead try using `TempData` as:

```
TempData["mydata"] = tmpOutput ;
```

and then retrieve `TempData` value in `TempOutput` action or directly use it in View as shown.

View :

```
<div>@Html.Raw(TempData["mydata"])</div>
```

Comment: Can you give me the whole code sample, what I need to change?

Comment: Use @Html.Raw(TempData["mydata"]) in your view.

Comment: @Exception  this is cool!  I am very new to MVC.  Are you saying that in using this approach I am able to send raw html coe to the page?

Comment: yes..and then html.raw will encode the string into required html in view..@Dean.DePue